# Blender 3.3.0 VSE audio pitch option is missing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

The option appears to be gone.
I created a project in blender 3.2.1 that has audio with shifted pitch.  When I open it in 3.3.0, the pitch shift is audible but the slider in the side panel of the VSE is gone.

Blender 3.2.1:
[image]

Blender 3.3.0:[image]

Where does this option live now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender 3.3.0 you now have it no longer in the *Sound* settings, but the *Time* settings below. It is no longer called *Pitch* but *Speed Factor*.

I guess this is because in the past people have mistaken the *Pitch* or **pitch control** (which in audio technology is controlling the pitch by varying the speed) with **pitch scaling** (which is changing the pitch while maintaining the speed).

[image: speed factor]

Comment: Interesting! It seems to function differently from the old one, but maybe I'm not remembering very well.

Comment: @AnsonSavage I didn't find it to be working different, it's basically just located elsewhere with a different name.

Comment: There's indeed some weirdness around this, but I think that I figured it out. If my findings are correct, the `Speed Factor` of sound strips does still behave exactly like it used to when it was called `Pitch`, but the confusing thing is that the `Speed Factor` of movie strips has a different effect. To achieve the same for videos, you need to have a separate `Speed` modifier strip and set it's `Speed Control` to `Multiply`, otherwise it shows the frame that would've been shown, had the video been playing with that factor applied from the beginning.

Comment: @Isti115 I don't know what you mean the _Speed Factor_ of movie strips has a different effect. If you set the _speed Factor_ of a video to 2, it plays the video twice as fast as normal. If you set the _Speed Factor_ of the audio to 2, it plays the sound twice as fast as normal - that's exactly the same effect. The only difference is that Blender changes the length of the video strip according to the factor whereas the audiostrip keeps its length and you have to adjust it manually.

Comment: @Isti115 What the _Speed Control_ does is you can adjust the length of the video strip to a certain frame range and the _Speed Control_ automatically fits the playback speed of the strip to fit into that range, without having to use a factor to get exactly the number of frames you want - for example to make it fit to the frame duration of an audio strip which you don't want to adjust - especially since Blender cannot change the duration of a sound file without changing the pitch to fit it to a video strip.

Comment: It seems like I missed a very important detail in my comment: I'm keyframing these properties. If you try to keyframe the `Speed Factor` of a video and an audio strip, you will see the difference. (The video will start to play backwards if you try to slow it down with keyframes of the `Speed Factor`, as it wouldn't have reached that point in time if it was playing with that factor from the beginning.) Also, if you keyframe the `Speed Factor` of an audio strip, it will go out of sync if you start playback from after the keyframe. :(

Comment: @Isti115 Yes, that's an important difference. The problem is, animating these values can result in discrepancies between the state a strip reached with the previous speed and where it should be according to the new speed. There are other similar problems in other areas of Blender as well, for example hair dynamics. If you randomize the rotation it's not looking so uniform. If you want to animate this random value, you have to set the hair to regrow so that the particle emitter reads the new value each frame. But then the dynamics don't work anymore because the hair is initialized each frame.