# How to match sound or video length by either speeding up or slowing down sound or video to match the length of the other?

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

Simple example:

Say I have a song and I want the video to match it perfectly in length (time/frames), by either speeding up or slowing down the video.

Is there a built in option to do this easily?

Maybe a plugin if there isn't a built in option?

I would guess the same option could be used for sound too, if it's the sound I want to speed up or slow down.

Comment: The solution I give below only works for video strips and image sequences, not for the sound. For speeding up or slowing down the sound you have the _Speed Factor_ option in the _Time_ settings, however this doesn't show in the strip length and it changes the pitch as well. Blender is not really usable as an audio editing software. Some information on the _Speed Factor_ you will also find in my answer here: [audio pitch option is missing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276050/blender-3-3-0-vse-audio-pitch-option-is-missing/276132#276132)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I have a sound strip which has a length of 600 frames, and a vidoestrip which has only 225 frames:

[image: short video]

In the *Sequencer* I select the video strip, then with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  I add an *Effect Strip* > *Speed Control*.

[image: add effect strip]

By default, the *Speed Control* effect is set to *Stretch* as you can see in the side panel to the right.

[image: speed control stretch]

If you now click and drag the right end of the video strip until it reaches frame 600 (or select it and move it with <kbd>G</kbd>), Blender will not simply repeat the last frame of the strip until the end, but actually make a slow motion video to fit the length.

[image: stretch video strip]